# My app is not working with iOS5

Tags: exception, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios5, uitableview

I'm struggling with my application due to the new version of iOs the 5th one...

I can launch the application normally but when I click on a tabBar item or on a button it crashes. I write the code of the exception plus the code of the view it can run :)

It works on every target but it crashes on ios5. Any idea?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view
>   controller: should have parent view
>   controller: but actual parent
>   is:'

```
@implementation PortCIAViewController
@synthesize tabBarController,topHeader,myApp;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 430);
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    //self.view = tabBarController.view;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllerA didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if(tabBarControllerA.selectedIndex==4){
        [(PortCIAAppDelegate*)myApp activeFullScreen];
        if(([(OrariViewController *)viewController segmentControllOrari].selectedSegmentIndex)==-1){
            [(OrariViewController *)viewController segmentControllOrari].selectedSegmentIndex=0;
            [(OrariViewController *)viewController segmentControllFascie].selectedSegmentIndex=[OrariViewController getCorrectFasciaOraria];
        }
    }
    else{
        [(PortCIAAppDelegate *)myApp deactiveFullScreen];
    }

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tabBarController release];
    [myApp release];
    [topHeader release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```